# C# insert string to database issue

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, ado.net

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ADO.Net + SQL Server 2008. I have some C# string type variables, and I want to insert them into database as type DateTime, any code samples?

My problem is how to do the conversion from string to database DateTime type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [`DateTime.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) method.

**Edit:** I suppose you use the [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx), then you just add the resulting c# `DateTime` object to the [`Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.DATA.SQLCLIENT.SQLCOMMAND.PARAMETERS);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true) collection.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the `DateTime.TryParse(string input, out variableName)`

Something like this:

```
DateTime safeDateTime;

if(!DateTime.TryParse("2010-09-15 10:00:00", out safeDateTime))
    safeDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Like that you will always have a value in the variable that the database can use. Otherwise you could implement a warning if you couldn't parse the date.